# Why can't I assign a 64bit integer to this field?

Tags: reason, bucklescript

Is there a numeric suffix I should be using to assign a numerical constant value to an `int64` type?

A moderately editted version of the error is:

```
We've found a bug for you!
{file}.re:321:20-31

321 │ let (rsid:int64) = 180785985722;

This has type: int
Somewhere wanted: int64
```

Where 'this' is referring to the number highlighted in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int64` literals use the suffix `L`:

```ml
let rsid: int64 = 180785985722L;
```

I don't think this is documented for Reason anywhere, but it is documented for OCaml, in the [manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#sss:integer-literals) and the [`Int64` module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Int64.html), which Reason tends to follow unless there's reason to deviate.